# Shaded rows are switched with/without jquery / css not being applied to nth-row

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Two questions:**

**First question**

- Inside snippet creator try remove/add jquery and see what's happening
  in output field. Shaded rows are switched !

**Second question**

- why click on a shaded row doesn't change its background to gold?

```js
$('.title').click(function() {
$('.act').removeClass('act');
$(this).addClass('act');
});
```

```css
.title{
cursor:pointer;
}

.title:nth-child(odd){
  background: #eee;
}

.act{
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
```

Comment: what you are trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> add/remove jquery and the row shading changes

that's because a `<script>` tag is *also* a child, put the `<script>` tag in the middle to see a more obvious example below.

More specifically, the css `.title:nth-child(odd)` says apply rule to `.title` where the *node* is `:nth-child`.  *Not* where the .title is the "nth-title".  Put another way, it's the same as `:nth-child(odd).title` - ie get the odd rows and if they are title, apply this style.

If you put some other, non-`.title` divs in the middle, you'll also see this happening.

```js
$('.title').click(function() {
  $('.act').removeClass('act');
  $(this).addClass('act');
});
```

```css
.title {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.act {
  background: gold;
}

.title:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
```

Normally you would have your `<script>` either in the `<head>` or just before closing `</body>` so this wouldn't normally be an issue.

Fix for snippets is to put the `.title` elements inside another `<div>`.

---

> why click on a shaded row doesn't change its background to gold

because the `.title:nth-child(odd)` supersedes/overrides the `.act` rule (not just because it's first)

You have 3 choices here:

- use `!important` (not generally recommended, it'll come back and bite you later)
- use a more specific rule `.title.act` (as provided in other answers, so not repeated here)
- apply the color to `:nth-child` as well

example:

```
.act,
.act:nth-child(odd) {
  background: gold;
}
```

```js
$('.title').click(function() {
  $('.act').removeClass('act');
  $(this).addClass('act');
});
```

```css
.title {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.title:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

.act,
.act:nth-child(odd) {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='title'>lorem</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem</div>
</div>
```

Comment: script tag should not be involved in this, because css say - `.title:nth-child(odd)` - so - `.title only`

Comment: I was just addressing that issue - see update.  "should not" - by who's reckoning?    Use a div that isn't a `class=title` instead of `<script>` tag - it does the same.

Comment: `by who's reckoning?` what is then the purpose of `.title` inside `.title:nth-child(odd)` ? Anyway - let's say - solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What if you defined it the other way: `:nth-child(odd).title`?  Would you agree that would give you what you're experiencing?  Find the nth-child nodes, then filter them to .title.  In css, you can define them either way.  So `.title:nth-child(odd)` is *not* `get .title then give me the odd ones` it's `get .title that are *also* odd ones`

Comment: No worries, when something like this doesn't work as you're expecting it, it can be difficult to find why it is working as it is.  There's plenty of examples in css and jquery that don't match 100% what they "say on the tin" intuitively, but once you know how it works, it does become intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

First question... it's because `nth-child` does **not** work against the `nth` instance of the specific **node type**.  It is finding the `nth` instance of a **child element** that just happens to be of that type.

So taking out the reference to jQuery results in the child elements being moved up one, and therefore the CSS picks up different elements.

---

Second question... you're hitting [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) where the differing parts of the CSS take priority over each other.  Another reference is from [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).

Because `.title:nth-child(odd)` is classed as higher priority than `.act`, the instructions in `.title:nth-child(odd)` are used.

If you wish to override this, you should put `!important` after the individual instructions, for instance...

```
.act {
  background:gold !important;
}
```

Or give the instruction a higher specificity...

```
.title.act {
  background:gold;
}
```

---

Example of fixed...

```js
$('.title').click(function() {
$('.act').removeClass('act');
$(this).addClass('act');
});
```

```css
#container .title{
  cursor:pointer;
}

#container .title:nth-child(odd){
  background: #eee;
}

#container .title.act{
  background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class='title'>lorem</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem</div>
</div>
```

Comment: pls, copy my code and place it inside snippet creator on this site. Then remove jquery and you'll see. Thanks for the second part.

Comment: Better idea - create a 2nd snippet in your question so other people don't have to do the work

Comment: Better idea - ask two questions, not one :)

Comment: I'd give this +1 for css specificity, but -1 for suggesting `!important` - that should be the last resort (also useful when trying to fix something in a library like bootstrap without repeating 100s of css rules)

Answer (score 0):

Shaded row doesn't change its background because of `CSS` give priority to specific property like `even/odd` as you used in Shaded color.

I think you want like this:-

```js
$('.title').click(function() {
$('.act').removeClass('act');
$(this).addClass('act');
});
```

```css
.title{
cursor:pointer;
}

.title:nth-child(odd){
  background: #eee;
}

.act{
background:gold !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
```

Comment: pls, copy my code and place it inside snippet creator on this site. Then remove jquery and you'll see. Thanks for the second part

Answer (score 0):

> Inside snippet creator try remove/add jquery and see what's happening
>   in output field. Shaded rows are switched !

In switched because the order has changed, you just remove the first one.

Try wrap the `.title` with some div.

```
<div>
  <div class='title'>lorem</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem</div>
  <div class='title'>lorem</div>
</div>
```

> Second - why click on a shaded row doesn't change its background to
>   gold?

Because it's overridden by another rule which is `.title:nth-child(odd)`

Try change `.act` to `.title.act`

```
.title {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.title:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

.title.act {
  background: gold;
}
```

See in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19eg3f70/)

Comment: The script tag. You said `try remove/add jquery`.

Comment: The :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent. https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: but why css/markup is changed on jquery add/remove ?

Comment: The CSS selector see `script` element not different as `div` element. So if you remove `script` element which is the first element. `:nth-child(odd)` will change.